# Accumulating elements of lists taking the criteria out of another list

Tags: list-manipulation, distributions

In order to find the critical values for the significance of a discrete distribution, for example `BinomialDistribution[20,0.6]`, i need a function which works on the cumulated distrubtion function `CDF` and the point density function `PDF`.

Let `pBin(x)` be the probability of value `x` and `cBin(x)` the cumulated probability. Now i want to know the first `x` where the statement `cBin(x)+1-cBin(y)>0.05` is true with y being the first value for which `pBin(x)>=pBin(y)` is true while `y>x`.

I tried to work with `Select` and `Position` but none of my attempts worked.

Comment: Please show the work you've done so far. Click on the gold help when editing for code formatting help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dt = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[20, 0.6], 100];

dist = EmpiricalDistribution[dt];
range = Range[Min@#, 1 + Max@#] &@dist["Domain"];
pairs = Select[MapIndexed[Function[{x, pos}, Join @@ {{x},
       Select[range[[First[pos] + 1 ;;]],
        PDF[dist, #] <= PDF[dist, x] && CDF[dist, x] + 1 - CDF[dist, #] >= .05 &, 1]}],
    range], Length@# > 1 &, 1]
(* {{8,16}} *)

Row[Histogram[dt, {1}, #, ImageSize -> 400, 
ChartElementFunction -> (If[pairs[[1, 1]] < {##}[[1]][[1, 2]] <= pairs[[1, 1]] + 1 || 
     pairs[[1, 2]] < {##}[[1]][[1, 2]] <= pairs[[1, 2]] + 1, 
   {Red, ChartElementDataFunction["Rectangle"][##]}, 
   ChartElementDataFunction["GradientRectangle", 
     "ColorScheme" -> "Rainbow", "GradientOrigin" -> Top][##]] &)] & /@ {"PDF", "CDF"}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very good method if the distribution is not too asymmetric. When choosing `BinomialDistribution[20,0.9]` however, the critical value is already reached at 16, but because this method can't find the corresponding `pos` it will instead give the pair {17,20}.

Comment: dt={19, 18, 18, 18, 16, 18, 19, 16, 17, 17, 18, 17, 19, 16, 19, 17, 17, \
19, 17, 17, 19, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 14, 19, 20, 20, 18, 18, 18, 18, \
18, 19, 15, 18, 18, 20, 17, 18, 19, 19, 20, 17, 19, 19, 17, 19, 17, \
19, 17, 18, 17, 19, 18, 19, 18, 20, 18, 19, 19, 18, 19, 18, 17, 18, \
18, 18, 17, 17, 19, 18, 18, 17, 17, 20, 18, 18, 15, 20, 18, 18, 20, \
16, 19, 17, 20, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 16, 20, 19, 20, 17}

Comment: In the PDF Histogram the probability of 16 is 0.05 alone, and the cumulated probability is 0.08

Comment: ... Looks like you are  taking   `First x such that (1) cBin(x) > 0.05 if  ylst= {y s.t y>x && pBin(x)<pBin(y)}=={}, (2) cBin(x)+1-cBin(ylst[[1]])>0.05  otherwise`. Is this correct?

Comment: well technically the probability of y=21 in the example should be 0, and the cumulated probability 1. Maybe the easiest solution is expanding the range for y.

I think your solution by distinguishing the cases should give the correct result too.

Comment: @kon, just changed the definition of `range`  to `range = Range[Min@#, 1 + Max@#] &@dist["Domain"];`